# Calculates coordinates for Ellipsoid

Tags: matlab, rotation, plot, octave

I want to plot an ellipsoid but I want its center and rotational point to be at the end of the ellipsoid instead of the center. How do I take the end point coordinates and convert them into center point coordinates. Also I want it to rotates around an end point instead of its center, Rotate() only uses the plots center.. Keep in mind the ellipsoid length varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rotate.html), it says:

> rotate(...,origin) specifies the origin of the axis of rotation as a three-element vector [x0,y0,z0].

Have you tried using your end point as the origin? This will override the default origin which is:

> The default origin of the axis of rotation is the center of the plot box. This point is not necessarily the origin of the axes.

Comment: @user758114 Can you explain further what the other half of your problem is? It is unclear to me.

Comment: I figured it out I had to multiply my major radius by sin(phi)^2 and Cos(theta)^2 to get the new x and z.